# I want an article that states Menelaus' spherical theorem and writes its proof.

Tags: reference-request, spherical-geometry, article-writing

I want an article that states Menelaus' spherical theorem and writes its proof.
The spherical case of this matter has been paid less attention and I only found this suitable link
https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MenelausAndCevasTheoremForSphericalTriangle/#more
So I can't refer this link for scientific use of this case, but I don't have access to an article about it either.(There is a lot of information about its use, but I have not found the case and its proof in an article)
A book or an article can solve my problem. Can anyone help me?